# Precompiling assets with Rails_Env set as production

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to run `$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` in order to: 1) minify my assets (following this answer: [How do I minify CSS in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215696/how-do-i-minify-css-in-rails-4)) and 2) use the production level variables in my JS (i.e., my JS has `ENV['variable']` and when I run a regular `rake assets:precompile` and then push to Heroku, the code runs with the development version of `ENV['variable']` rather than the production one.

However, I'm running into a problem where I get an error:

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

The error is in response to this line in the JS file that I'm compiling:

```
var items_to_be_added = [{
  id: '<%= ItemName.where(name:"Jacket").first.id %>',
  name: "Jacket",
  number: 1
}
```

But the weird thing is that I ran a `heroku run gem list` and `pg 0.15.1` is installed already.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your database.yml file look like?

Comment: @evanbikes interesting I was using SQLite it looks like... but I tried removing it, still have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to specify Heroku's postgres database in your database.yml.

First, on the command line: `heroku config`

It should spit out `DATABASE_URL: postgres://<username>:<password>@<host>/<database>`

Put those values in your database.yml file so that your local environment knows how to connect to Heroku's database.

Then, asset precompilation should be able to query the production database and compile the assets.

Obviously, don't check this into version control.

Comment: Ok now I'm getting: `Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).` But I just did a `heroku run gem list` and can confirm that I have `pg (0.15.1)` installed

Comment: Your bundle is bundled in Heroku for production, but your local rake task is using your local gems. I would just move the pg gem—and whatever gems you need for precompiling—out of the production group so that they bundle locally. Or you could do `RAILS_ENV=production bundle`

Comment: THANKS. [a million other errors later and it's working]