# Comment breaks css rule

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, uglifier

I have a rails app and I am using bootstrap and some other vendors js and css.

Everything was is fine on development but when I moved it to production (heroku) some css rules are being ignored.

This is one of the rules that are being ignored:

```
@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .drawer--sidebar .drawer-hamburger {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  /*! Left */
  .drawer--sidebar.drawer--left .drawer-nav {
    left: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
}
```

Funny thing is that `.drawer--sidebar .drawer-hamburger` behave as expected but `.drawer--sidebar.drawer--left .drawer-nav` is not detected.

Taking a look at the generated css I got this: (expanded)

```
@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .drawer--sidebar .drawer-hamburger {
    display:none;
    visibility: hidden
  }

  /*! Left */
  ;.drawer--sidebar.drawer--left .drawer-nav {
    left: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd
  }
}
```

I've tried to remove comments with copyright using   `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(comments: :none, copyright: false)` but it did not work.

I would simply remove the offending comments but we download dependencies before precompile assets on every deploy.

How can I instruct rails to ignore those comments?

**EDIT**

Just for clarification.

`config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(comments: :none, copyright: false)` does work, but only with js files.

`config.assets.js_compressor = :sass` as stated on [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215696/how-do-i-minify-css-in-rails-4) does not work

Comment: Is this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215696/how-do-i-minify-css-in-rails-4

Comment: I'm not a Rail dev, but it seems like you are showing the `js_compressor` instead of the `css_compressor`. Are you using Uglifier for the CSS?

Comment: @HieuPham already tried that, didn't work. The offending comments are still there

Comment: @Quantastical I found that problem just now, but still. Did not manage to find a way even with css_compressor

Comment: Looks like your compressor isn't correctly handling "unnecessary" semicolons. What happens if you write `visibility: hidden}` instead of `visibility: hidden;}`?